# java JSON text encoding issue

Tags: java, json, character-encoding, google-search-appliance, windows-1252

In my application I retrieve search results in JSON format from an external tool called Google Search Appliance(GSA).

The JSON result from GSA is very large and therefore I prefer to modify the GSA JSON result into something more suitable for displaying on my webpage.

If I directly display the GSA JSON result without formatting it in my java code I'm not facing any encoding issues on my webpage.

But if I format the large GSA JSON result into a suitable JSON format in my servlet java code I'm facing encoding problems.
Example -  `“All Access Pass”`  gets displayed as `ÂAll Access PassÂ`.

I return the modified json from my servlet to the webpage use the following code -

```
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

I have tried to change the charset to `iso-8859-1` but it does not make any difference.

I edit my original JSON in the following manner -

```
        String responseText = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();

        JSONObject resultJSON = new JSONObject();
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseText);

                    JSONArray resultJsonArray = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("RES");

                    JSONObject searchResultJSON = null;

                    for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < resultJsonArray.length(); iCnt++) {

                        searchResultJSON = new JSONObject();

                        JSONObject obj = resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(iCnt);
                        JSONObject metaTagObj = obj
                                .getJSONObject("MT");

                        if (metaTagObj.has(("title"))) {
                         searchResultJSON.put("title",metaTagObj.get("title").toString());
                        }
             resultJSON.accumulate("RES", searchResultJSON);
    }
   response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"); 
   response.getWriter().print(resultJSON);

    }catch(JSONException e){}
```

The modification to the original JSON which I'm going here can be done in JavaScript which would solve my problem but it is something which I do not want to do.

1. Is there a way to find out the encoding format of the text in the original GSA JSON?
2. How can I avoid the java code from changing the text encoding in the original GSA JSON?

Please help me understand what is going on here and how I can avoid this problem.

Comment: I'd be curious how the original JSON formats the same characters.  What is the "suitable JSON format" into which you convert it?  How do you convert it?

Comment: The only difference in my code is that when I display the original JSON, I set the response content type as ("application/json"). But if I do the same thing with the modified JSON I was getting "??" characters so I set it as "application/json;charset=UTF-8".

Comment: Those quotes usually come from Microsoft apps... So I googled a bit and found [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?72944-How-to-handle-Smart-Quotes-pasted-into-TextArea-input), which makes me wonder if you need to read about "_Microsoft's Windows-1252 character encoding_".  Or maybe I'm way off...

Comment: Then I found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1667732.aspx/1)... (boy I'm bored right now!)

Comment: I convert the original JSONObject String into org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject. Then I iterate over the individual objects within the name value pairs on the JSON and set it into another org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject object. eg - newJSONObject.put("title",originalJSON.get("T").toString());

Comment: k I'm editing my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text encoding problem was happening because the call which is made to the GSA server using Apache HTTP Client was using a default content encoding character set of `iso-8859-1` but the GSA server expected the HTTP Client request and response to be in `UTF-8` encoding.

This problem got resolved after setting the encoding for HTTPClient -

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.getParams().setContentCharset("UTF-8");
```

And the servlet response encoding to

`response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");`